# Rails Cache is storing the value but not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am caching an external API response into Rails. I read from the cache and it returns nil as expected. I store into the cache it returns true, I read again and it returns my value, but if I make another request from the client with the same parameters it returns nil as if the value was not stored.

```html
    def create
     cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new
       url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + params[:zip] +"&units=imperial&APPID=4e66533961b500086bf6bd7c37d4b847"
       @weather =  fetch_weather(url)
       p cache.read(params[:zip])
       weather = cache.read(params[:zip])
       p weather
       p weather.nil?
       if weather.nil?
        cache.write(params[:zip],@weather,:expires_in => 30.minutes)
       end
       p cache.read(params[:zip])

     render json: @weather
    end
```

So for example I will use a zip code 94016 for the first time and it will return

```html
nil
nil
true
<RestClient::Response 200 "{\"coord\":{\"...">
```

I will run it again with the same zip code and get the same response. I have enabled caching in my development environment. I am not sure why its not working. Thank You.

Comment: How are you running your code, exactly?

Comment: There is a front-end client that triggers the create action in the controller. So the front-end passes the zipcode to the back end as a param and triggers the controller action upon form submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since every time you request this action you create a  cache store:

```
cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new
```

you should put this line in your config file:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

then use Rails.cache to get or set a cache.